# how to make required attribute of input type tag work only for specific buttons?

Tags: php, html, forms

I've made a form in html with 2 input fields `first name` and `last name` and added the `required` attribute to the input type tag. I've also made two buttons `Submit` and `View`. If both fields are empty, it shows the `please fill out this field attribute` message. When I click the submit button, the data from my form goes into my sql database using php, which is fine. But when I click the view button, I just want to display a message WITHOUT filling the `first name` and `last name` text areas. How do I do this with the view button?

tl;dr: I want the 'required' attribute of the input type tag to work only for the submit button and not the view button. How should i do this? I'm using HTML for the form, CSS for styling and PHP for the sql entry. Thanks.

Comment: what is the type for your "view" button, Im assuming the type for "submit" is submit

Comment: Yes, it is of submit type.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that with JavaScript, for example by giving each of your inputs an ID, you could then detect when the view button is clicked and remove the "required" attributes.

Here is a JQuery example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#view").click(function() {
        $("#test1").removeAttr("required");
        $("#test2").removeAttr("required");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="example.php" method="POST">
  First name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="test1" required="required"><br />
  Last name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="test2" required="required"><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> | <input type="submit" id="view" value="View">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1x7ts4s9/)

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to do this without JavaScript?

Comment: @shraey.chikker Unfortunately no, the `required` attribute is part of the DOM (Document Object Model). JavaScript can manipulate the DOM but CSS cannot. PHP can also manipulate the DOM, but it's a server-side language, not client-side which is what you need here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also prevent the default action for click event. In this case, the code would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#view").click(function() {
    return false;
  }); 
});
```

Or using preventDefault:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#view").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }); 
});
```

Both seems to work fine. #view (like in aforementioned answer) is id for button that you want to prevent from triggering required attribute.